# Mac OS 10.7.5 compatible with Bitcoin-Qt.app?

Tags: wallet, mac, synchronization

Program runs but doesn't seem to be able to synchronize with network.  Is there more to installing program than just dragging into applications folder?

I'm also confused about why I don't have a Bitcoin folder in Application Support folder of Library folder...  (If invisible, how do I make it visible?)

I'm a returning user after being away for about a year....  trying to access an old wallet.dat file saved on USB stick

Comment: A few more details please.  The current Bitcoin-Qt (v0.7.0) works with that version.  What version are you running?    Does the client show connections?  Is the block count stuck, or just loading sloooowwwly?   Are you on an encrypted filesystem?

Comment: Bitcoin-QT isnt much a Mac friendly. Despite the fact is for Mac users. I strongly recommend you use Electrum. Which is recommended also by bitcoin.org

Answer (score 1):

Apple 10.7 hides the Users Library folder (where bitcoins saves its stuff), it's there, just not visible. Open terminal and enter
chflags nohidden ~/Library
to make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Finder to access the folder Bitcoin-Qt stores the blockchain and its other files:

- select the **Go** menu; pick **Go To Folder…**
- type `~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`
- press Return